# How to convert a letter B under the code 0x412 to a normal B letter (code 0x42) in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x

I have encountered a rather strange phenomenon (B) copied from the Internet different than the letter B typed on my personal computer, how do I convert the letter B from the Internet to a normal B letter in Python, Thank you!

Comment: u+0412 is not the letter B, it is a [Cyrillic Ve](https://unicode-table.com/en/#0412). Why do you want to convert one to the other?

Comment: I analyze data coming from the Internet, strangely only the letter B is not deciphered properly, What do you propose to do?

Comment: Stop, something you're not telling us, something you may not know, is going on. I have been on “the Internet” for many years and have been getting Latin Bs just fine. You're telling us that every single site on the entire Internet is changing Latin Bs to Cyrillic Ve? Then it's probably something on your machine, and trying to change the internet is probably not going to work. Or is it only certain sites? Investigate those sites, don't start changing sites until you have found what is causing this.

Comment: This is a specific site from which I kept the information, until now I had no special problems.

http://tqen.mot.gov.il/safety

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.replace`

```
print('Вaby'.replace('\u0412', 'B'))
# Baby
```

If you have many such substitutions to make, you can also use a translation table

```
trans = str.maketrans('\u0412\u0432', 'BB')
print('вВВв'.translate(trans))
# 'BBBB'
```

Comment: Is there no more way to "automatically" convert alphanumeric characters without a conversion table?

Comment: @SagiNadav There is [`str.casefold`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold), but that doesn't work in this scenario.  `B` and `B` are two different letters in different alphabets, there's no relationship between them other than the fact that they look similar.  I'm not aware of any python built-in for weeding out subtly incorrect graphemes.